# Always compile as a single file even when not publishing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation

Is it possible to make visual studio always compile as a single file during builds without having to publish every time?

Current Properties:

```
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
```

Comment: I have made an answer. If you accept it, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense to compile to a file during compilation, and It will hinder subsequent work.

And currently the release single file is only available after NET Core 3.0. For details, you can refer to the [link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview#publish-a-single-file-app---visual-studio)